# Issues while implementing jenkins docker image+chrome+ruby unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, docker, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to setup jenkins using the official jenkins docker image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y ruby-full
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt -y autoremove
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt install -y wget
RUN gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc --format-executable rake
RUN gem install selenium-webdriver
RUN gem install bundler
RUN npm install -g node-mongo-seeds

#Permissions granted to jenkins user to do a gem install
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/gems
RUN apt-get install -y patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /usr/local/bin

# We need wget to set up the PPA and xvfb to have a virtual screen and unzip to install the Chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -y wget xvfb unzip

# Set up the Chrome PPA
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

# Update the package list and install chrome
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.35
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
RUN mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH

USER jenkins
```

While running the job the browser won't open and hit the localhost.
I tried hitting 'google.com' as well

```
google-chrome --headless --no-sandbox 'https://www.google.com'
```

still no success

```
    Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
[0531/130727.949511:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(217)] Waited 17 ms for network service
```

I am not able understand why jenkins user not able to open the browser.

- Google Chrome 74.0.3729.169
- ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881)
- ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
- Jenkins 2.164.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=74.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v74.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.35* and the *Chrome Browser v74.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v74.0**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.8/) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v74*** level. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Will this solution and update soon

Comment: Facing this new issue 
options.add_argument('--headless')
d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  *(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)*

Comment: @TheRookie Your main issue of _...Chrome failed to start: crashed (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)..._ seems to have got **resolved** now. _...Chrome failed to start: crashed (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)..._ looks to be a new issue altogether. Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please?

Answer (score 1):

So as per @DebanjanB comment it resolved the driver issues but as per the new issue of chrome crashing I resolved it by just adding

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```